# How to update field when delete a row in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let I have a table named `customer` where customer table has a field named `deleted_by`. 
I implement `softDelete` in `customer` model. Now I want to update `deleted_by` when row delete. So that I can trace who delete this row.

I do search on google about it But I don't found anything.

I use laravel 4.2.8 & Eloquent

Comment: this package can help you https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-revisionable-upgrade

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may update the field using something like this:

```
$customer = Customer::find(1); // Assume 1 is the customer id

if($customer->delete()) { // If softdeleted

    DB::table('customer')->where('id', $customer->id)
      ->update(array('deleted_by' => 'SomeNameOrUserID'));
}
```

Also, you may do it in one query:

```
// Assumed you have passed the id to the method in $id
$ts = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$data = array('deleted_at' => $ts, 'deleted_by' => Auth::user()->id);
DB::table('customer')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

Both is done within one query, `softDelete` and recorded `deleted_by` as well.

Comment: It works. I accept this answer. But I can't up vote because my reputation is not enough to up vote

Answer (score 5):

Something like this is the way to go:

```
// override soft deleting trait method on the model, base model 
// or new trait - whatever suits you
protected function runSoftDelete()
{
    $query = $this->newQuery()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());

    $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

    $deleted_by = (Auth::id()) ?: null;

    $query->update(array(
       $this->getDeletedAtColumn() => $this->fromDateTime($time), 
       'deleted_by' => $deleted_by
    ));
}
```

Then all you need is:

```
$someModel->delete();
```

and it's done.

Comment: +1, I like the idea but also I would pass a parameter to optionally update the `deleted_by` field. `If($deleted_by) {...}`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Yes, that could do too. It depends on the required functionality. Provided is just an example of how to handle it effectively.

Comment: Of note, this doesn't work if you are using the original trait and create a new trait to override the `runSoftDelete()` method. It comes back with this fatal error: `Trait method runSoftDelete has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on XXX` where `XXX` is your model name.

Comment: @JeremyHarris Obvioulsy, that's how traits work in PHP. But.. aliasing for the rescue :) If you want to override the method in new trait, then simply use `use SoftDeletes { runSoftDelete as unusedSoftDelete; }` and there won't be collision.

Comment: Aha, very nice. I wasn't aware of trait aliasing.

Comment: super nice I was searching for this

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but what you could do (in the customer model) is the following....

```
public function delete() 
{
    $this->deleted_by = auth()->user()->getKey();
    $this->save();

    return parent::delete();
}
```

That would still allow the soft delete while setting another value just before it deletes.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use a [Model Event](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events) for this.

```
<?php
class Customer extends \Eloquent {
    ...
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        // We set the deleted_by attribute before deleted event so we doesn't get an error if Customer was deleted by force (without soft delete).
        static::deleting(function($model){
            $model->deleted_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $model->save();
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you just delete it like you would normally do.

```
Customer::find(1)->delete();
```